# When I running pytest, I receive the following error message from jupyter

Tags: python, pytest, jupyter

When I running pytest, I receive the following error message from jupyter

There is no "Application Data" folder in the directory indicated by Jupyter.
Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Even when running Jupyter as an administrator, the error was not resolved.

[image]

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) by editing your Question. Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.